# Inject Code via Jquery Around specific Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a quarrel with jQuery. I'm trying to inject a span with a specific class around a part of the content on an HTML page.

For example, this is the html I have:

```
<td class="">4 <a href="#">view</a></td>
```

And what I want is

```
<td class=""><span class="num_cell">4</span> <a href="#">view</a></td>
```

I feel this may be easier than I'm making it -- can anyone help?

Comment: I have been trying to combine .html() and .wrap(), but can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should also work:

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().first().wrap("<span class='num_cell'>");
})
```

Comment: This was a great solution, but it seem to wrap my element multiple times in the same class. I could not get it to recitify.

Comment: Actually, as time passed I ran into a few problems that you're solution seemed to clear up perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to cover only textNode you should use `.contents()` which also returns textNodes as item.

Please check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/contents/ there is an example which is exact answer of your question.

```
    $("p").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).wrap("<b/>");
```

After your comment, I don t think you need a loop for this, can you try the below code?

```
    $("td").contents().filter(function(){ return this.previousSibling == null && this.nodeType != this.TEXT_NODE; }).wrap("<span/>");
```

`this.previousSibling == null` means it is first if you want to check if it is the first element or not

Cheers.

Comment: I added @rafek 's each loop to this, and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I edited my answer and I thing you don t need to use an extra loop let jQuery handle these things.

Comment: Although this was a great solution, I ran into some problems down the line and @rafek 's solution seemed to work perfectly with those. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/zkjyV/30/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("td").each(function() {

    var $div = $(this);        
    var $a = $div.find("a"); 

    $div.find(a).remove();
    var number = $div.html();

   $div.html("<span class='num_cell'>"  + number + "</span>").append($a);
});


});​
```

I did it with a div so it would run in jsFiddle. But you can replace the div with a  and it should work just fine :)

Here's the final version http://jsfiddle.net/zkjyV/33/

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. lots of answers already, here's a pure javascript answer for what it's worth.. I added an ID to the cell to make it simple, but you could easily take it from there to make it generic..

**HTML**

```
<td class="" id="targetCell">4 <a href="#">view</a></td>​
```

**JS:**

```
    //get the parent reference to cache and avoid requerying the DOM
var parentCell = document.getElementById('targetCell');
// get the value of the first node (in this case TextNode)
var result = parentCell.firstChild.nodeValue;
// remove the TextNode
parentCell.removeChild(parentCell.firstChild);
// create a new span
var newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
//just for testing
newSpan.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
//populate the value
newSpan.innerText = result;
//inject before the first child
parentCell.insertBefore(newSpan, parentCell.firstChild);​
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RBhLB/1/